# How to get transformation matrix described in xaml back from visual tree

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have some xaml, for example

```
 <Path Name="path3" RenderTransform="0.476026892662048,0,0,0.476026892662048,485.101623535156,-68.1086807250977" />
```

In my code I construct visual tree from xaml ( XamlReader.Load(xaml) ). After this operation I need get transform matrix back, but property `(path.RenderTransform as MatrixTrasform).Matrix` haven't values that defined in xaml(values in this property are like 1,0,0,1,0,1).

How to get transformation matrix back?

Comment: The Xaml you have posted is not valid. That may account for the default matrix you are getting. Is that your actual Xaml? Best to test it in a user control and see if Visual Studio throws up an error.

Comment: Visual Studio don't throw error. And transformation applied to path. And in designer path is showing correctly.

Comment: Visual studio should have underlined it in red and given an error (mine does). In any case, go with AnthonyWJones's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The Xaml should look like this:-

```
<Path Name="path3" Data="Path data here">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.476026892662048,0,0,0.476026892662048,485.101623535156,-68.1086807250977" />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Comment: Xaml is not mine. I cant't modify it. And I need process when matrix defined in RenderTransform attribute. Why I can't get info about matrix when it defined in attribute (transformation applied correctly, designer don't throw error)?

Comment: @Alex:  You can't modify it and you can't parse it.  I'd say you are in trouble.  Regardless of what the designers may or may not be doing the fact is that from the __silverlight__ XamlParser's perspective that Xaml is not valid.  If you can't modify it at source then you may be able to write some hoop jumping string manipulation code to ram it into shape.  However since the source clearly doesn't understand correct Silverlight xaml (could the source be WPF oriented?) then you are likely to come up against something else and then something else...  It sounds like a world of pain to me.